# nginx problem with url (multiple parameters, rename, delete extension)

Tags: php, nginx

I have a server with php7.4 and nginx (aws ebs), I admit that I don't know anything about nginx, I would just like a small example of how I could do that when I go to this address:

```
www.example.com/mytestone?id=100&conf=2$...etc (multiple vars)
```

point to this on my server

```
www.example.com/test.php?id=100&conf=2$...etc (multiple vars)
```

I have searched for information but I always find configurations to remove the extension but not to change the address name and delete the extension and multiple vars at the same time. please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need an HTTP 301/302 redirection or an internal URI rewrite?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I need an internal uri rewrite.

Comment: Assuming you already have a PHP handler `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` block, just use `rewrite ^/mytestone$ /test.php last;` line outside of any locations. That would preserve any of your query arguments.